# What is the Delphi 10 equivalent to DesignIntf?

Tags: delphi, synedit, delphi-10.1-berlin

Just updated the SynEdit RunTime module for Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but now I need to update the DesignTime Module... The Designer units from Delphi XE versions do not appear to be available in 10.1.

What is the recommended Design Editor and Interface module to replace the old Delphi Designers?

I was thinking there would be built-in XAML designers, since the new Delphi supports .NETCore.

Is there an alternate designer to use for FMX and cross-platform projects?

example found... requires FMX.Types unit and a header over the class
https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/writing-a-simple-firemonkey-tlistlayout-implementation/

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types;

type
  [ComponentPlatforms(pidWin32 or pidWin64 or pidOSX32)]
  TListLayout = class(TControl)
```

Here's how I changed my headers for XE, Delphi 10 and Firemonkey

```
(*
Directive           Description
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  LINUX               Defined when target platform is Linux  // FOR KYLIX

  // FOR WINDOWS VERSIONS USE VCL
  WIN32               Defined when target platform is 32 bit Windows
  WIN64               Defined when target platform is 64 bit Windows
  CLR                 Defined when target platform is .NET

  WINVCL // ADDING TO REPRESENT ALL VCL platforms

  // FOR OTHER USE ELSE
  // *)
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  {$DEFINE WINVCL}
{$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
    {$DEFINE WINVCL}
  {$ELSE}
    {$IFDEF CLR}
      {$DEFINE WINVCL}
    {$ENDIF}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}

uses
{$IFDEF LINUX} // Kylix is target platform
  QControls,
{$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF WINVCL}
    VCL.Controls,
  {$ELSE} // ALL OTHER PLATFORMS USE FIREMONKEY CONTROLS
    FMX.Controls,
    FMX.Types,
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
  System.Classes;
```

And the new controls start out like this now...

```
[ComponentPlatforms(pidWin32 or pidWin64 or pidAndroid or pidOSX32)]
TMyCustomComponent = class(TControl)
```

Comment: gotta luv people giving me a negative for asking a question that's never been posted. cyber-bullies. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has changed. Your design-time package should require `designide.dcp` and the necessary runtime package. `Designide` contains what you need.

---

#### Use the Getit Package Manager

But this can be a lot simpler. I just did the following:

- In the IDE, selected `Getit Package Manager` from the `Tools` menu.
- Searched for `Synedit`
- Found `Synedit Turbo Pack` and clicked `Install`
- A dialog popped up. I clicked agreement and it went on installing Synedit (although with the old 230 version suffix - this ought to be changed to 240 for Berlin)

After that, I could continue editing what I was editing before this, and the latest Synedit was installed.

`SyneditPropertyReg.pas` still uses the same units, like `DesignIntf`, `DesignEditors`, etc.

Note that now, there are (at least) two packages: `SyneditDD.dpk` and `SyneditDR.dpk`. The latter is the runtime package, the former is the designtime package and that should require the runtime package as well as `designide`. I think the installer compiled a little more, but it went so fast, I couldn't see properly.

Comment: a while back (last year) I reverted to an older SynEdit and updated it, because there were some bugs in the newer version... too many chefs in the pot. it was running hella slow. It was a case of less is more... faster and more stable. In this case I updated that last edit of mine. I will push some corrections or a branch back to the original package when I'm done. Also, removed a number functions from the Unicode support as they are standard Delphi functions found in System. Wanted to eliminate any potential conflicts there.

Comment: Thx for the info... added DesignIDE and have installed the package I patched for 10 yesterday. Very happy it was so easy!!!

Comment: btw: I rolled in support for every version of Delphi, but I only tested in XE5 and Berlin.

Comment: Is there an alternate designer to use for FMX and crossplatform projects?

Comment: @JosephPoirier: What do you need to do differently at design-time between VCL and FMX?  As far as property/components editors are concerned, they use the same designers.

Comment: Keywords required to convert... FMX.Types in the uses clause on any unit containing Classes. uses clause should precede Class (Component)

good sample in an online XE2 book... I will add the ref l8r

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- it was the runtime side that I was concerned with. like many coders, I have a number of custom VCL components I've made, and I wanted to port them over to FMX framework. I feel I have a pretty solid base for transformation now, that I added to my question at the top for anyone to reference. Thx again for the help. You are quite brilliant.